# using @Angular/flex-layout responsive features causes template parse error

Tags: flexbox, angular-cli, ng-class, angular

## Using flex-layout 2.0.0-rc.1

Scanning through stack I haven't been able to find anything regarding this. (rc.1 is quite new)

I am following this [documentation](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/ngClass-API) for the @Angular/flex-layout and would like to make use of the **Responsive Features** section. I would like to provide conditional classes on an element at various media query breakpoints.

Below is a simplified example of my code.

```html
<div class="box" [ngClass]=" {'remove-margin-top': false}"
                 [ngClass.sm]=" {'remove-margin-top': true}">

    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

When the above code only contains `[ngClass]=" {'remove-margin-top': false}"` everything works nicely. No template parse errors.

The problem comes when adding `[ngClass.sm]=" {'remove-margin-top': true}"` that on template parsing generates...

> Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'ngClass.sm' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

I've been able to confirm that the FlexLayoutModule is imported into the module correctly and other flex-layout specific directives work fine.

### Main Module Imports

```typescript
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
...

@NgModule({
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  MomentModule,
  FlexLayoutModule
],
```

### Part of Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler": "4.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/core": "4.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/forms": "4.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/http": "4.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.2",
"@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router": "4.0.0-rc.1",
"angular2-moment": "1.1.0",
...
}
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0-rc.1",
"@types/core-js": "0.9.35",
"@types/hammerjs": "2.0.34",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.35",
"@types/node": "6.0.60",
"@types/socket.io-client": "1.4.27",
"@types/source-map": "0.1.27",
"@types/stompjs": "2.3.0",
"@types/webpack": "1.12.34",
"@types/webrtc": "0.0.21",
...
}
```

Comment: I think I may havee found an more accurate use of this feature. https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/src/demo-app/app/docs-layout-responsive/responsiveStyle.demo.ts